# Sequence puzzle in rows

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

The below is a number puzzle. It should be read left to right, top to bottom.
[image]

Question 1: What is the next two rows of numbers?
Question 2: How was this reached?

Comment: It's a very nice puzzle, but unfortunately it's been asked here several times before...